# Media query not working on HTML form

Tags: html, css

I would like the font size for my form label and input fields to scale down from 18px to 10px when the browser width reaches 1460px or less.

I read that it is not possible to get fonts to automatically 'scale down' as such when the browser width decreases, and that I would need to use media queries instead.

Therefore I have put a media query at the top of my style tags asking the font size for my label and input to display at 10px when the screen size is 1460px, but it doesn't seem to work. The rest of my code is working fine however, so it must be something to do with the way I am coding my media query.

If someone could offer some help that would be much appreciated.. my code is pasted below.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1460px) {
  label input {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  resize: vertical;
  transition: 0.3s;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Typ1451-Medium;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 7px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  border: 1.25px solid #ea0088;
}

label {
  padding: 21px 12px 12px 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Typ1451-Medium;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 2.5% 20% 0 20%;
}

.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <form action="signin.php" method="post">


    <div class="left">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="* Please complete">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="right">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="* Please complete">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the html of  first name last name? Because your selector is for input that is inside label tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector — `label input` — doesn't match any elements in your HTML.

None of your `input` elements are descendants of your `label` elements.

Perhaps you meant `label, input` to select `label` elements **and** `input` elements. If so, then it still wouldn't work because you define the `input` font-size with a more specific selector later on (and the most specific selector [wins the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade)) and  the `label` in a similar way (it doesn't have a more specific selector, but when selectors are equal, the *last* one wins the cascade).

Comment: I took your advice Quintin and managed to fix this by moving my media query to the very bottom of my styles (instead of at the top) and made a slight amend to my media query to make the input more specific as you suggested.. many thanks!

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1460px) {
            label, input[type=text] {
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you CAN scale fonts up or down with the viewport size. There is a method with `calc()` and `vw` units:
Basically you do something like `font-size: 3vw` and then set max and min font sizes.
Here is a [link to the calculation](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/#controlling-the-rate-of-scale) on Smashing Magazine. The rest of the article is pretty interesting, too.

You can extend this even further and optimize the font size with media queries.

Have fun! :)